# My django project can't runserver on my own pc

Tags: django

Hi all and thanks for you taking the time to see my question.

I am a newbie on the python.

I'm just want to start a site on my pc. When I use "django-admin.py" to make a project,All things like good. But When I use "python manage.py runserver",it notices me that:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'test.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

I check my code, all things are right. The manage.py writes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

my folder is this:

```
hua@sun-Rev-1-0:~/hua/mydjango/mysite$ ls
manage.py  mysite
```

and the project is also right;

```
hua@sun-Rev-1-0:~/hua/mydjango/mysite$ tree mysite/
mysite/
├── __init__.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Now I use the python to see my os.path:

```
hua@sun-Rev-1-0:~/hua/mydjango/mysite$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/bin/python2.7', '/home/hua/hua/mydjango/mysite/~share', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

I can't find where my wrong.

Comment: in your error it trace about `test.settings` but in your project it's `mysite.settings`

Answer (score 0):

There's only `/home/hua/hua/mydjango/mysite/~share` in your `sys.path` - you're still missing `/home/hua/hua/mydjango/`

Add it and it should work.

You could also move your project into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and run it there.

Comment: oh wait, what is this `test.settings`? Doesn't your project got the name `mysite`? Please post your `settings.py` (without the database stuff)